# How to generate new [voucher_no] that start from 1 on every new day and add [voucher_no] on same date(when needed)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using a SQL Server database and my table is `iRecord`. It contains a column `voucher_no` which has a `identity(1,1)` attribute.

If `[voucher_no]` ended on 10 on 25 july, then it should be started from 1 again on 26 july. And if add another `[voucher_no]` on 25 july, then it should be `voucher_no = 11` of 25-july.

I am working on accounting software in which we maintain vouchers by voucher numbers of each day and I am inserting these voucher number through generated by auto in sql so that sequence is matter here.

So if we forget to record one more voucher on previous date so I should be able to add new voucher record in that previous date with last generated voucher no +1.

Currently, our view is based on some logic by inserting on this table simple

```
create table iRecord
(
    [voucher_no] int primary key identity(1,1)
    [description] varchar(50) not null,
    [RecordDate] Date not null,
)
```

My expected output can be understand the logic that if I generate `[voucher_no] = 10` on '25-july-2019', and now I generate a new voucher the next day, this time my `voucher_no` should be started from 1 again on '26-july-2019'.

Could anyone help me regarding this issue?

Comment: This is tricky - you cannot use an `identity` column - that will just be counting up, and no reset for the next day. You could use `SEQUENCE` - but the requirement to be able to go back to a previous day and get a new, sequential value for that day would require to have a separate `SEQUENCE` for each day - rather messy. Quite honestly, in this case, I'd create a `voucher` table with entries per day (`Day DATE, VoucherNo INT`) and then just make sure (through locks and clever access) to avoid handing out duplicate voucher id's per day

Comment: yes you are right, Can you share some short code of SQL or c# code regarding this issue, Shorter Code logic that I could get .?

Comment: just use max(voucher_no) + 1 for voucherno with date